# Send Outlook email using text in an Excel textbox - Error 424: Object required

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to send an email with Outlook using text in a textbox (I named it tx in Excel) as body.

When I run the code, there is an error on the line:

```
strbody = tx.Text
```

> Error 424: Object required

```
Sub SendMail()

Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim strbody As String

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

strbody = tx.Text

'On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = "..."
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = Cells(3, 2)
    .Body = strbody

    .Send
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: `tx` isn't defined in your sub, is it a public variable? What seems to be issue? Please explain what is not going as expected!

Comment: @R3uK I think it's the name of a textbox on the worksheet

Comment: What's the problem here? When you run this, do you send a blank e-mail, does it error, does it do nothing? Using `.Send` might cause some issues if your security settings are restricting it - swap it out with `.Display` to see what is/isn't working.

Comment: Yes, tx is the name of the textbox on the worksheet.

Comment: When I run the code, there's an error on the line : strbody = tx.Text (Error 424 : Object required).

Comment: I think .Send isn't the problem since I just tested with an email sample.

Comment: @FrancisZHENG : The error is pretty clear, it says that you don't have an object on that line, so indeed `tx` isn't recognized just like this. There is a LOT of question solving that issue, I answered one just yesterday! ;)

Comment: Yeah, I looked through your profile. But I didn't find it... I just don't know how to call a textbox and its text. It's more complex than I thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `Sheet's name` by the name of the sheet where your textbox is
in `strbody = ThisWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet's name").Shapes("tx").ControlFormat.Value`

```
Sub SendMail()

Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim strbody As String

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

strbody = ThisWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet's name").Shapes("tx").ControlFormat.Value

'On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = "..."
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = Cells(3, 2)
    .Body = strbody

    .Send
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your answer. There's an error at line : strbody = ThisWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet's name").Shapes("tx").ControlFormat.Value  (Error 438 : Object doesn't support this property or method)

Comment: @Francis : Ok so try replacing `ControlFormat.Value` by `DrawingObject.Text`

Answer (score 0):

You could use CDO?  Here's some quick VBA code I put in a test function in Excel VBA (with the email addresses and SMTP server address redacted):

```
Sub test()

    Dim strbody As String
    strbody = "Test Email" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "TEST EMAIL"

    Dim iMsg As Object
    Set iMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")

    With iMsg

        .Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") _
            = "whateverYourSMTPServerIs"
        .Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") _
            = 25
        .Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") _
            = 2   'Stands for sending using CDO
        .Configuration.Fields.Update

        .To = "someemail@someplace.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .From = "someemail@someplace.com"
        .Subject = "Test Email"
        .TextBody = strbody
        .Send
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: That just doesn't answer the question... Read the comments please

Comment: Thank you. But I think my problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I misinterpreted "But it's not the right way to do" as "I don't want to have to reference Outlook libraries just to send an outgoing email", not "this code is what I want to use, but it isn't working".